# Facebook SDK CanvasAutorize attribute redirects my ajax call and doesn't reach the controller code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a FB app that is working nice with the postbacks from within MVC but when i try to post some data to a controler that has the requireauthorize attribute, using jquery $.post() , FB redirects it and I can't get it work. It only returns a block of script code instead, which i believe is the ridirection from FB or something.

Example: UI button Click code

```
//Client side JS button click event
$.post("/Friends/Save", "{ 'requestIds':'"+ response.request_ids + "'}", function (data) {
    alert("Friend requests saved!");
});
```

My MVC controller code:

```
[HandleError]
public class FriendsController : Controller
{
    [CanvasAuthorize(Perms = "user_about_me")]
    public JsonResult Save(string requestIds)
    {
        //Save to DB
        //(....)

        return Json(new { Status = "Saved!" });
    }
}
```

If i comment the attribute everything works fine, Anyone can help me out on how can this be done  ?
I need to check for every post that it is done by a FB logged in user!

Thanks in advance! Have a good day all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced this same issue.  My solution was to separate the Get and Post controller methods (via [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] and [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] ) and only put the [CanvasAuthorize] attribute on the Get method.  When I perform my ajax Post I include the signed request in the post which I can use to get the access token.

Comment: Hi Pat! Thanks for nice info. Could you please post a piece of code showing the post with the signed request and also the server side code using getting the access token? I'm a little new in this FB app world and with the constant changes all the time is even more difficult for me... i would appreciate it very much!

Comment: I believe I found something edentical in the net http://weblogs.asp.net/kon/archive/2010/11/15/getting-started-with-facebook-c-sdk.aspx is this what you're doing? And is it also correct to assume that as you send over the session token, no redirection is needed to be done by the canvasauthorize attribute right?

Comment: The approach in that blog entry looks like the same basic approach I can use.  He is passing up the auth_token obtained from the Javascript client library.  I actually do this myself as well as passing the signed_request.  In production I have logged a small number of errors where the auth_token is passed up null for some reason I don't understand, in which case I try decrypting the signed_request and find a good auth_token from it.